# In users' e-mail addresses, remove all references to a domain

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

On our cloud-hosted O365 tenancy, I would like to run a PowerShell script which looks at *every user* and removes any reference to an e-mail domain I'm trying to get rid of.

As an example, if we have the following user:

**Jimbob Goodemails**

- Jimbob.Goodemails@newdomain.com
- Jimbob.Goodemails@olddomain.com
- Jimbob.Goodemails@domain.onmicrosoft.com (the default O365 domain)

I would like to remove @olddomain.com addresses (in the above case, Jimbob.Goodemails@olddomain.com) from every user.

On most of these accounts, that domain will be set up as an alias - e.g. `smtp:Jimbob.Goodemails@olddomain.com` in the `proxyAddresses` field.

However, some users (far fewer, perhaps only 3 or 4) may have it as their main e-mail address (e.g. `SMTP:Jimbob.Goodemails@olddomain.com` in `proxyAddresses` but also as the `mail` and `UPN` attributes). These users can just use the default O365 e-mail address instead.

I have tried the following script, to no avail:

```
foreach($i in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited) {
　 $i.EmailAddresses |
　　　 ?{$_.AddressString -like '*@olddomain.com'} | %{
　　　　　 Set-Mailbox $i -EmailAddresses @{remove=$_}
　　　 }
}
```

It sits for a while, then appears to finish, but nothing has changed.

I have used an Active Directory PowerShell script which does this for my AD-synchronised users, so I'm primarily looking to change Cloud users and groups.

It would also be useful to know how to search for such users too.

Answer (score 0):

**The Method:**

Create an Array of your Current SMTP's:

```
$SMTPs = $Mailbox.EmailAddresses -split ","
```

Remove the Unwanted SMTP Addresses:

```
$SMTPs | ? {$_ -notmatch 'olddomain.com'}
```

Then Update The Mailbox with the filtered SMTPs:

```
Set-Mailbox $Mailbox -EmailAddresses $SMTPs
```

**In your Example:**

```
foreach ($i in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited) 
{
$SMTPs = $i.EmailAddresses -split "," | ? {$_ -notmatch 'olddomain.com'}
Set-Mailbox $i -EmailAddresses $SMTPs
}
```